# Sorting li tags according their numeric Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have look other sorting examples. But I could not implement them to my site.

My code is like this.

```
<ul class="selectable" id="third">
<li id="0">John</li>
<li id="0">Tom</li>
<li id="30.00">Petar</li>
<li id="100">Johnson</li>
<li id="33.00">Jackson</li>
<li id="0">Jack</li>
<li id="10.0">Allen</li>
</ul>
```

How can i sort them according their li id tag ?

Modified : instead of id, if i put title how can i sort them according title ?

Comment: `id` must be unique in document

Comment: Use custom `data-*` attributes if you want to set any specific values to elements.

Comment: Try this: http://trentrichardson.com/2013/12/16/sort-dom-elements-jquery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` should be unique , so use custom `data-*` attribute . And you can use native javascript `sort()` for sorting.

```js
$('.selectable li').sort(function(a, b) {
// get list items
  return $(a).data('id') - $(b).data('id');
  // compare values
}).appendTo('.selectable');
// update sorted dom elements
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="selectable" id="third">
  <li data-id="0">John</li>
  <li data-id="0">Tom</li>
  <li data-id="30.00">Petar</li>
  <li data-id="100">Johnson</li>
  <li data-id="33.00">Jackson</li>
  <li data-id="0">Jack</li>
  <li data-id="10.0">Allen</li>
</ul>
```